# Spark application uses only 1 executor

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing, partitioning, executors

I am running an application with the following code. I don't understand why only 1 executor is in use even though I have 3. When I try to increase the range, my job fails cause the task manager loses executor. 
In the summary, I see a value for shuffle writes but shuffle reads are 0 (maybe cause all the data is on one node and no shuffle read needs to happen to complete the job).

```
val rdd: RDD[(Int, Int)] = sc.parallelize((1 to 10000000).map(k => (k -> 1)).toSeq)
val rdd2= rdd.sortByKeyWithPartition(partitioner = partitioner)
val sorted = rdd2.map((_._1))
val count_sorted = sorted.collect()
```

Edit: I increased the executor and driver memory and cores. I also changed the number of executors to 1 from 4. That seems to have helped. I now see shuffle read/writes on each node.

Comment: Are you running in cluster mode, standalone mode? Are you running locally or on a cluster somewhere?

Comment: I am running in cluster mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ..maybe cause all the data is on one node

That should make you think that your RDD has only one partition, instead of 3, or *more*, that would eventually utilize all the executors.

So, extending on Hokam's answer, here's what I would do:

```
rdd.getNumPartitions
```

Now if that is 1, then repartition your RDD, like this:

```
rdd = rdd.repartition(3)
```

which will partition your RDD into 3 partitions.

Try executing your code again now.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your code is ending up with only one partition for RDD. You should increase the partitions of RDD to at least 3 to utilize all 3 executors.

Comment: Nice hunch, +1 and an answer following yours from me. :)